# On a clarification regarding shankara bhashya gambirya nirnaya

Tags: adi-shankaracharya

so I was reading the introduction by radhakrishnan sir on advaitha dipika by pandith ananth krishna Shastri in that he(radhakrishna sir ) mentions that there is a work called shankara bhasya gambirya nirnaya by mahamahopadhyaya ramasubba shastrigal tiruvasanallur , which says the advaithic view traditionally attributed to shankara bhavadpada is not true and it has some inclination of dualism
Pls confirm about this work and what's in it or any information about it or is it being refuted , since it's impossible to even think bhavadpada's work would point towards dualism in any way shape or form
Thank you